# Elixir 'if' and 'and' not working as expected

Tags: ecto, elixir

I have this code:

```
if Map.has_key?(dbShop, "id") && Map.has_key?(dbProduct, "id") do
  case Api.Repo.insertProductShop(conn, dbShop.id, dbProduct.id) do
    {:ok, productShop} ->
      {:ok, productShop}
    {:error, changeset} ->
      Tuple.append(errors, "could not insert product in the Shop")
  end
else
  IO.puts("(dbShop, id) && Map.has_key?(dbProduct, id) failed")
  IO.inspect(dbShop)
  IO.inspect(dbProduct)
end
```

Code execution makes it into the the `else` clause and the logs this to the console:

```
(dbShop, id) && Map.has_key?(dbProduct, id) failed
%Api.Shop{__meta__: #Ecto.Schema.Metadata<:loaded, "shops">, id: 23,
 latitude: -36.846691, longitude: 174.7745803, name: "Yard Bar & Eatery",
 placeId: "ChIJp6DGbAdIDW0RcbnExyPHvCk"}
%Api.Product{__meta__: #Ecto.Schema.Metadata<:loaded, "products">,
 brand: "baba", description: " zhzngshshhshs", id: 34, image: "no-image",
 name: "Nsn", numberOfVotes: nil, rating: nil}
```

So we can see that `dbShop` and `dbProduct` both have an `id` and somehow the code execution never makes it into the `if` clause. What am I doing wrong with my `if` clause? I want check that they both have an `id` and if so, go inside the `if` clause.

Full function in router:

```
  post "/products" do
    errors = {}
    postedProduct = conn.body_params
    dbProduct = %{}
    dbShop = %{}
    case Api.Repo.insertProduct(conn, postedProduct) do
      {:success, product} ->
        dbProduct = product
        case Api.Repo.insertProductCategories(conn, postedProduct, dbProduct.id) do
          {:ok, categories} ->
            {:ok, categories}
          {:error, failed_operation, failed_value, changes_so_far} ->
            Tuple.append(errors, "could not insert productCategories. Product already has that category")
        end
      {:error, changeset} ->
        IO.puts("product not inserted")
        Tuple.append(errors, "could not insert product. Product already existed")
        IO.inspect(errors)
    end

    if Map.has_key?(postedProduct, "shop") do
      case Api.Repo.insertShop(conn, postedProduct["shop"]) do
        {:ok, shop} ->
          dbShop = shop
          if Map.has_key?(dbShop, :id) && Map.has_key?(dbProduct, :id) do
            case Api.Repo.insertProductShop(conn, dbShop.id, dbProduct.id) do
              {:ok, productShop} ->
                {:ok, productShop}
              {:error, changeset} ->
                Tuple.append(errors, "could not insert product in the Shop")
            end
          else
            IO.puts("(dbShop, id) && Map.has_key?(dbProduct, id) failed")
            IO.inspect(dbShop)
            IO.inspect(dbProduct)
          end
        {:error, changeset} -> # shop already exists
          # Tuple.append(errors, "could not insert shop")
          if Map.has_key?(dbShop, "id") && Map.has_key?(dbProduct, "id") do
            case Api.Repo.insertProductShop(conn, dbShop.id, dbProduct.id) do
              {:ok, productShop} ->
                {:ok, productShop}
              {:error, changeset} ->
                Tuple.append(errors, "The product has already been added to the shop")
            end
          end
      end
    end

    if tuple_size(errors) > 0 do
      IO.puts("errors")
      IO.inspect(errors)
      conn
        |> put_resp_content_type("application/json")
        |> send_resp(200, Poison.encode!(%{
            successs: "success",
            errors: errors
        }))
    else 
      conn
        |> put_resp_content_type("application/json")
        |> send_resp(200, Poison.encode!(%{
            successs: "success"
        }))
    end
  end
```

Comment: Your keys are atoms. Try `Map.has_key?(..., :id)`.

Comment: Also, what are you trying to do with this expression? If those two values are always Shop and Product structs, they'll always "have" the key `:id`, even if the value of `:id` is nil or false.

Comment: @Dogbert Thanks! I thought since it didn't have `:` in front of the `id` it was not an atom. Regarding your second comment, `dbProduct` only gets populated if the product gets inserted into the database. If it didn't get populated it is most likely it is already in the database (unique constraint).

Comment: What do you mean by "get populated"? If `dbProduct` is not a struct this will throw an exception, and if it is a struct, it'll always have the `:id` field.

Comment: @Dogbert I just added the full function to the question so you can see. It needs a big refactor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your map has an atom `:id` as key, not the string `"id"`, so your `if` should be:

```
if Map.has_key?(dbShop, :id) && Map.has_key?(dbProduct, :id) do
```

If the value is guaranteed to be non-nil if present, you can also shorten this to:

```
if dbShop[:id] && dbProduct[:id] do
```

Accessing a value using the bracket syntax will not throw an error if the key is not present, and instead return `nil`, which is a falsy value in Elixir.

Answer (score 1):

Using `if` in Elixir is a code smell and a hint that the code might be re-written in more explicit manner. Here I would go with [`Kernel.SpecialForms.with/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.SpecialForms.html#with/1), and instead of:

```
if Map.has_key?(dbShop, :id) && Map.has_key?(dbProduct, :id) do
  # true
else
  # false
end
```

use:

```
with %{id: shopId} when not is_nil(shopId) <- dbShop,
     %{id: prodId} when not is_nil(prodId) <- dbProduct do
  # true
else
  ^dbProduct -> IO.puts "prodId is nil"
  ^dbShop -> IO.puts "shopId is nil"
end
```